# How do I use strict parsing in dayjs.tz?

Tags: dayjs

Strict parsing is [documented](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format) for the `dayjs()` constructor but not for the `dayjs.tz()` one. Is it possible to enable strict parsing for the `dayjs.tz()` constructor? If not, is there some way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Converting to Zone docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/converting-to-zone), it looks like you can achieve this using the `dayjs().tz()` instance method (instead of the `dayjs.tz()` constructor) by setting its second parameter to true.

> On passing a second parameter as true, only the timezone (and offset) is updated, keeping the local time same.

```js
// parse using strict mode (but not in correct timezone)
let d = dayjs('2024-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);

// update timezone but keep same local time
d = d.tz("America/Toronto", true);
```